# swipe on android non responsive

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, events

So I have some code to trigger a jquery event and what this code does is every time a user swipes left/right over an area it triggers the event and adds a log to the console.

This has been working fine on my ipad and iphone but today i have come to test it on two seperate android devices and have had little joy.

I have to swipe 20/30 times before it actually logs a swipe.

I wondered if I have an error in my code?

```
var maxTime = 1000,
    // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
    maxDistance = 50,
    // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the swipe
    target = jQuery('.pageSize'),
    startX = 0,
    startTime = 0,
    touch = "ontouchend" in document,
    startEvent = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    moveEvent = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    endEvent = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

target.bind(startEvent, function(e) {
    // prevent image drag (Firefox)
    // e.preventDefault();
    startTime = e.timeStamp;
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
}).bind(endEvent, function(e) {
    startTime = 0;
    startX = 0;
}).bind(moveEvent, function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        currentDistance = (startX === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(currentX - startX),
        // allow if movement < 1 sec
        currentTime = e.timeStamp;
    if (startTime !== 0 && currentTime - startTime < maxTime && currentDistance > maxDistance) {
        if (currentX < startX) {
            // swipe left code here
            //slideMobile("forward", pageSize);

            console.log("swipeForward");
            jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');
        }
        if (currentX > startX) {
            // swipe right code here
            //slideMobile("back", pageSize);

            console.log("swipeBackward");
            jQuery(window).trigger('swipeBackward');

        }
        startTime = 0;
        startX = 0;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible related bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4549

Comment: have tried the e.preventdefault. not much joy

Comment: the problem is as soon as you prevent default it will swipe once and then not again